# How to add clickable Links to UILabel with attributedText in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I used [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/) to display formatted text in my apps. DTAttributedTextView also supports clickable links.
Since iOS6 we can use the setAttributedText function to display attributedStrings in UILabel.
But how can I display Links that are clickable? Is there a way to call a delegate Function etc. when a link is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS 6.0 UILabel still cant display clickable links.

However you could use a UITextView instead. The textview can detect links, but the link detection only work if editing of text is disabled. Limitations are that you cant do something like this in BBCode [url=www.apple.com]Apples Website[/url].

Answer (score 3):

Here is example code to hyperlink UILabel:
Source:http://sickprogrammersarea.blogspot.in/2014/03/adding-links-to-uilabel.html

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
UITextField *loc;
TTTAttributedLabel *data;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 80, 25) ];
[lbl setText:@"Text:"];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
loc=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 20, 300, 30)];
//loc.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
loc.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
loc.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
//[loc setText:@"Enter Location"];
loc.clearsOnInsertion = YES;
loc.leftView=lbl;
loc.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
[loc setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:loc];
[loc setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(110, 70, 70,30);
UIButton *srchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
srchButton.frame=frameimg;
[srchButton setTitle:@"Go" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[srchButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
srchButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[srchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(go:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:srchButton];
data = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 120,self.view.frame.size.width,200) ];
[data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
[data setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
data.numberOfLines=0;
 data.delegate = self;
data.enabledTextCheckingTypes=NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
[self.view addSubview:data];
}
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
NSString *val=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",url];
if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"mailto"]) {
          NSLog(@" mail URL Selected : %@",url);
    MFMailComposeViewController *comp=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [comp setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        NSString *recp=[[val substringToIndex:[val length]] substringFromIndex:7];
        NSLog(@"Recept : %@",recp);
        [comp setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:recp, nil]];
        [comp setSubject:@"From my app"];
        [comp setMessageBody:@"Hello bro" isHTML:NO];
        [comp setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentViewController:comp animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:val]];
}
}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
if(error)
{
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Erorr" message:@"Some error occureed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alrt show];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
else{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{
NSLog(@"Phone Number Selected : %@",phoneNumber);
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber]]];
} else {
    UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [Notpermitted show];
}
}
-(void)go:(id)sender
{
[data setText:loc.text];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"Reached");
[loc resignFirstResponder];
}
```